What is $\int \left(\frac{xe^{\sin(x)}(\sqrt{1-x^2})}{\cos(x)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}-i^{87}}\right) \textrm{d}x$?
Disclaimer: For this problem, please assume that I have the knowledge of a student who just finished a basic calculus course, having just learned integration techniques such as trigonometric substitution, partial fraction decomposition, and more.
At first, I thought some form of substitution would work here, plugging in different chunks of the numerator to see if I would get anything resembling the denominator. Unsurprisingly, that was a fruitless search.
In addition, one may also notice the weird power of the imaginary number $i$ just hanging about, making my day way worse. I immediately noticed that since $87 \equiv 3 \mod{4} $, that meant $i^{87}=-i$.
Me, who had only known how to integrate real numbers in a single variable, was finally bewildered on how I can proceed further after the integral had only slightly transformed to $\int \left(\frac{xe^{\sin(x)}(\sqrt{1-x^2})}{\cos(x)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+i}\right) \textrm{d}x$. Can we integrate if the integrand contains imaginary numbers? Is this even a solvable integral?
